# Trying to learn fragments, why fragment is not showing up

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

Here is the xml for my main layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_placeholder"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <ImageView
        android:contentDescription="image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</FrameLayout>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Code for fragment class

```
public class ExerciseFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_layout, container, false);
    return view; 
}


}
```

and code in main activity for showing fragment on click of a button:

```
ExerciseFragment fragment = new ExerciseFragment();
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, fragment);
ft.commit();
if (fragment.isVisible()) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
} else 
    Toast.makeText(this, "nooooo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

The toast says "noooo" meaning the fragment is not visible, and it still shows an image which i set up in the framelayout holder which i want to replace. Any ideas why the fragment is not showing up?

EDIT: COMPLETE CODE FOR MAIN ACTIVITY

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.workout_menu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

    case R.id.menu_exercise:
        ExerciseFragment fragment = new ExerciseFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, fragment);
        ft.commit();
        if (fragment.isVisible()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "works", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        } else 
            Toast.makeText(this, "nooooo", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 

        break;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
}
```

Comment: the fragment may not be still attached

Comment: what does that mean? how to i get it to remain attached? im new to fragments

Comment: where in the activity you have `ft.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, fragment);`. there is no button in xml that i see

Comment: What happens if you remove the ImageView from the FrameLayout?

Comment: the image is just to see that there is something there (the framelayout is there). if i remove it nothing changes...the button to add the fragment is in the action bar

Comment: @user3217136 you don't have button in activity's xml. so where do you have the button??

Comment: its not a button, its a menu item in the action bar

Comment: @user3217136 post that code and edit your post mentioning the same

Comment: @user3217136 remove the imageview and you should see the fragment the toast will still be noooo coz it is still not attached. but you should see the fragment once it  is attached you can display toast

Comment: how do i attach the fragment?

Comment: @user3217136 Check out my answer below. I hope it will help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `ft.replace(R.id.fragment_placeholder, fragment);`, try using `ft.add(R.id.fragment_placeholder, fragment);`. Since the `R.id.fragment_placeholder` doesn't contain a fragment yet, you aren't replacing anything, you are merely adding on to the layout. The `.add(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)` function should work for your case. In the future, if you are going to change the fragment contained in `R.id.fragment_placeholder`, use `.replace(int containerViewId, Fragment fragment)`.

Hope this works!

Comment: If i'm using .add() to a framelayout, do you know how i could add more than 1 of the same fragment

Comment: By adding additional layouts inside your parent layout `R.id.layout`, you can add more fragments or replace the fragment currently contained in `R.id.fragment_placeholder`